# How do you keep changes separate with Git?

Tags: git

I know we're suppose to be using topic branches for fixes in Git but I'm wondering - do you all keep one repository while working on your local machine with all your work or a separate repository for each change? It seems like keeping them all in one repository would be a pain, no? Your build files become stale every time you switch!

Comment: I just branch. I imagine its going to be more popular than cloning each time

Comment: Using multiple local repositories is a valid branching model. It isn't really considered the git way of doing things though. Local branches tend to be easier to manage in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

A repository represents a deliverable across all changes across time.

It would be best to have one place for all of your changes, otherwise it would require a lot of syncing.